# how does a multi-threaded server work?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization

I've got from someone this example with a multithreaded server on android:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/singlethreaded-server.html

But I have a few difficulties in understanding a part of the code:

```
while(! isStopped()) {
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (isStopped()) {
            System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
            return;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection", e);
    }
```

What I don't understand is, what happens when I have an exception at this line:

```
clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
```

From what I can tell is that this function gets called:

```
private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
    return this.isStopped;
}
```

But how it gets to close that socket?  Cause if u get exception in the attempt to accept a client you should close the socket returned by accept.

I assume that this is done in here:

```
public synchronized void stop() {
    this.isStopped = true;
    try {
        this.serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
    }
}
```

But where is `stop()` called,how it gets to make the connection between `isStopped()` and `onStop()`....And what is with that "synchronized"?

Hope I've been clear with my unclarities!  Thank u in advance:)

Comment: while(true) won't suck up your battery since accept() waits for connections and will 'pause' the thread until someone try to connect (or until someone close it, in which case the exception is risen).

Comment: But does isStopped() calles internally for stop()?

Comment: isStopped do what is in its function body, nothing else.

Comment: anyway I've looked at the link you provide and it seems quite well explained. I suggest you to run, debug and hack the code to see how it runs. for what synchronized do, look here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: and when do I have stop() called......:-S:-S:-S

Comment: when stop is called, two things are done. First is positioning the isStopped boolean to true, which will prevent in all cases the while to loop again. The second statement is this.serverSocket.close(), which tells the system that your process is not listening to requests anymore(and it will btw release some resource allocated to the opened server). once server.stop() is called, no connections can enter and this.serverSocket.accept() will rise an exception cause it can't accept them anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably moved on but for posterity...

> what happens when I have an exception at this line

```
clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
```

If you get an exception inside of accept then no socket is returned so there is nothing to close.  Either `accept()` returns a valid socket that you should handle and then close *or* it throws an exception.  Never both.

> where is `stop()` called?

Stop looks to be called from the outside world by some caller that wants to shutdown the server socket.  With a server, you create a server-socket and then you accept individual connections to remote clients, which returns a socket for that client.  Each of the client handlers need to close their own individual connections.  When the server is shutting down (in this case when `stop()` is called), the server-socket is then closed.

Once `stop()` is called then the server socket is closed and the `accept()` method will throw an exception.  That's why there is a `if(isStopped())` check in the code to avoid throwing an exception.

> how it gets to make the connection between `isStopped()` and `onStop()`

`isStopped()` is a private method that tests to see if someone has called the `stop()` method.    I assume `onStop()` is an Android method?  They are not related although someone might want to call `singleThreadedServer.stop()` inside of `onStop()`.

> what is with that `synchronized`?

The synchronized keyword is used by multithreaded programs as a mutex and memory barrier.  It only allows 1 thread to be executing inside of the `synchronized` block at one time.  It also makes sure that all of the local variables are synced between the threads and central memory.  See the java docs:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Having that private method be synchronized is really gross IMO.  I assume this is being done to make sure `isStopped` has been updated.  I would have used a `volatile` boolean or `AtomicBoolean` instead.